# Is AtomicCmpExchange() broken?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

If you make a new multi-device application project, set `Project > Option > Compiling > Optimization : True`, and then copy the code below to `unit1.pas`:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.StdCtrls,
  System.Classes,
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FKey: integer;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  FKey := 2;
  var LCompareKey: integer := 2;
  AtomicCmpExchange(FKey{target}, LCompareKey{NewValue}, LCompareKey{Comparand});
  if FKey <> LCompareKey then raise Exception.Create('Error 2');

  TThread.queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      if LCompareKey <> FKey
        then raise Exception.Create('Error 3');
    end);

end;

end.
```

Why does this code crash on Win32 on `if FKey <> LCompareKey then raise Exception.Create('Error 2');`?

I'm using **Delphi 10.4 Sydney Update 3**. I didn't yet try in Delphi 11 Alexandria, so I don't know if it's working in that version.

Is there any workaround except deactivating the optimization?

Another question - is it really safe to activate the optimization?

Comment: It seems like codegen is broken broken if variables are captured. Try `TInterlocked.CompareExchange`

Comment: yes TInterlocked.CompareExchange work great (strange because it's only use internally atomicComExchange and inlined) , but AtomicCmpExchange is already used everywhere, not only in my code but also in tiers code :( do you know if it's crash also in Alexandria ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :( noone is perfect, I guess this compiler too don't desperate :( I will add an entry in QP as soon as it's will work again, because QP is also not perfect :(

Comment: Also fails on Delphi 11 Alexandria

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36303

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, codegen for `AtomicCmpExchange` is broken on Win32 compiler when optimization is turned on.

Problem happens in combination with anonymous method variable capture that happens in `TThread.Queue` call. Without variable capture, assembly code for `AtomicCmpExchange` is properly generated.

Workaround for the issue is using `TInterlocked.CompareExchange`.

```
...
var LCompareKey: integer := 2;
TInterlocked.CompareExchange(FKey{target}, LCompareKey{NewValue}, LCompareKey{Comparand});
if FKey <> LCompareKey then raise Exception.Create('Error 2');
...
```

`TInterlocked.CompareExchange` function still uses `AtomicCmpExchange`, but at place of call it works with captured variables through parameters instead of directly and generated code is correct in those situations.

```
class function TInterlocked.CompareExchange(var Target: Integer; Value, Comparand: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := AtomicCmpExchange(Target, Value, Comparand);
end;
```

Another, less optimal solution would be turning off optimization around broken method `Button1Click` with `{$O-}` compiler directive and then turning it back on with `{$O+}`

Since `AtomicCmpExchange` is Delphi intrinsic function, its code is directly generated by compiler when it is called and bad codegen only affects that procedure, not general code - in other words anonymous method capture is working correctly in other code (unless there are other, bugs in compiler, unrelated to this particular one).

In other places in RTL where `AtomicCmpExchange` is used, there is no code where variable capture is involved, so RTL, VCL and FMX code is not affected by this issue and optimization can be turned on in application.

**Note:** There may be other optimization bugs in compiler that we don't know about.